# TryParseExact from french dates with month full name

Tags: c#, datetime, globalization

I need to parse dates such as

`7 août 2008` (August 7th 2008)

I tried this :

```
var french = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "d MMMM yyyy", french, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed_date);
```

which returns false

However, this code

```
var french = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
var test = new DateTime(2008, 8, 7);
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", french));
```

outputs

`7 août 2008`

as expected.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: For me your first code block works fine (returns true) for given input string.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dvA1AV. Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: Any chance that there's some character with different ANSI code in your original string? I had some similar issues with space with not-standard ANSI code.

Comment: Do you have additional characters in your input? Like unprintable chars or a BOM from a file, maybe?

Comment: Indeed @Fildor and #Piotr. See my answer. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TryParseExact` is actually Exact.

In my case, I needed to ignore white spaces (probably not printable) using

```
var styles = DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite;
var french = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "d MMMM yyyy", french, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed_date);
```

to get the expected result.